# Change a php variable based on the pathname using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme, but I use this single installation for 2 domains. Both domains point to the same installtion.

Now, I want to use jQuery, based on the domain name in the address bar, to change the color scheme of the WP Site.

Now, in the WP-dashboard, you can change the color of the theme. Now this interface where you can choose the theme color, is defined in the follwing code inside a rt_styling_options.php file:

```
    array(
        "name"      => __("Theme Style",'rt_theme_admin'),
        "desc"      => __("Please choose a style for your theme.",'rt_theme_admin'),
        "id"        => THEMESLUG."_17_style",
        "options"   =>  array(
                        "blue"     => "Blue Style",
                        "purple"   => "Purple Style", 
                        "orange"   => "Orange Style",                       
                        "brown"   => "Brown Style",                                                 
                        "rose"   => "Rose Style",       
                        "green"   => "Green Style",     
                        "grey"   => "Grey Style",       
                        "gold"   => "Gold Style",                               
                        ),
        "default"   => "blue", 
        "type"      => "select"),
```

Here is a screenshot of the WP-Dashboard where you can choose this color:

[image]

**Question:**

**How do I change the value of that color based on the domain name in the address bar?**

It will go something like this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if (pathname == 'domain2.com'){

    change the value of the theme color   

}
```

**Additonal Info (important):**

Here is the php file (theme.php) and relevant function where this color value above is called into: ( see if(get_option(THEMESLUG."_17_style")){ )

```
function load_styles(){


        wp_register_style('theme-reset', THEMEURI . '/css/rt-css-framework.css', 1 , false, 'all');
        wp_register_style('theme-style-all',THEMEURI . '/css/style.css', 2 , false, 'all');

        if(get_option(THEMESLUG."_17_style")){          
            wp_register_style('theme-skin',THEMEURI . '/css/'.get_option( THEMESLUG."_17_style").'-style.css', 3 , false, 'all'); //dark skin               
        }

        wp_register_style('prettyPhoto',THEMEURI . '/css/prettyPhoto.css', 5 , false, 'screen');

        if(get_option(THEMESLUG."_font_face")){
            wp_register_style('rtfontface',THEMEURI . '/css/fontface.css', 100 , false, 'all');
        }       


        wp_enqueue_style('theme-reset');
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style-all');  
        wp_enqueue_style('rtfontface'); 
        wp_enqueue_style('prettyPhoto');         
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-colortip', THEMEURI . '/css/colortip-1.0-jquery.css');      
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-jcarousel', THEMEURI . '/css/jcarousel.css');  
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-flexslider', THEMEURI . '/css/flexslider.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-nivoslider', THEMEURI . '/css/nivo-slider.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-nivoslider-theme', THEMEURI . '/css/nivo-default/default.css'); 
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-skin');

        wp_register_style('theme-ie7',THEMEURI . '/css/ie7.css', 6 , false, 'screen');
        $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'theme-ie7', 'conditional', 'IE 7' );
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-ie7');

        wp_register_style('theme-ie8',THEMEURI . '/css/ie8.css', 6 , false, 'screen');
        $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'theme-ie8', 'conditional', 'IE 8' );
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-ie8');


        wp_register_style('theme-style',get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ), 4 , false, 'all'); //WP default stylesheet 
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style');

        if (class_exists( 'Woocommerce' ) ) { //woocommerce style for rt-theme
            global $woocommerce, $suffix;

            wp_enqueue_style( 'rt-woocommerce-styles', THEMEURI.'/rt-woocommerce/woocommerce.css');

        }
    }
```

---

---

---

**UPDATE:** @Patrick

•Changes in **theme.php**

```
   $themeId = "";
        $pathname = get_site_url();

        if($pathname == 'domain2.com')
       $themeId =  THEMESLUG."_17_style2";
        else 
           $themeId = THEMESLUG."_17_style";

        wp_register_style('theme-skin',THEMEURI . '/css/'.get_option($themeId).'-style.css', 3 , false, 'all');
```

NOTE: I removed this from the original theme.php file:

```
if(get_option(THEMESLUG."_17_style")){  .....}
```

•Changes in **rt_styling_options.php**: just added the following right after the first set, as you specified

```
array(
        "name"      => __("Theme Style",'rt_theme_admin'),
        "desc"      => __("Please choose a style for your theme.",'rt_theme_admin'),
        "id"        => THEMESLUG."_17_style2",
        "options"   =>  array(
                        "blue"     => "Blue Style",
                        "purple"   => "Purple Style", 
                        "orange"   => "Orange Style",                       
                        "brown"   => "Brown Style",                                                 
                        "rose"   => "Rose Style",       
                        "green"   => "Green Style",     
                        "grey"   => "Grey Style",       
                        "gold"   => "Gold Style",                               
                        ),
        "default"   => "gold", 
        "type"      => "select"),
```

Comment: you would use pure php for this as js cant change a php var

Comment: yeah of course...did not think straight there

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't change those Wordpress PHP array values with JQuery. (JQuery is client side while PHP is server side).

What you can do instead is use JQuery to target the CSS and HTML elements based on the URL Path name... This won't be easy though because you'll have to take into consideration all the elements affected by the theme.

OR, you'll have to use PHP to do all the logic between switching themes based on the URL Path.

Looks like you can use `<?php get_site_url(); ?>` to get the URL Path with PHP in Wordpress. See more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url

**Update**

It seems like you can change your current theme by making direct calls to the wordpress SQL database:

```
function switchTheme($theme) {
  global $wpdb;
  if (isset($theme)) {
    $queries = array("UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default'
                      WHERE option_name = 'template';",
                     "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default'
                      WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';",
                     "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default'
                      WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';");
    foreach ($queries as $query){
        $wpdb->query($query);
    }
  }
}
```

`option_value` is where you would put your theme name.

Sources:

http://designgala.com/how-to-change-wordpress-theme-directly-from-database/
http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-trick-change-theme-programatically

Also there are the `switch_theme` and `update_option` functions from Wordpress.

Similar to the above SQL queries, you can use `update_option` to update your theme like:

```
update_option('template', 'theme_name');
update_option('stylesheet', 'theme_name');
update_option('current_theme', 'theme_name');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: yeah of course! Didn't think about that. But how will I pass the url path into php? Of course there must be a php function I can run when the website is requested from the webserver by the browser, based on the url the browser passed to the webserver?

Comment: PHP is capable of getting the URL Path usually. Did you see this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url

Comment: Updated answer, might give you some help on changing the actual theme through PHP/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the template to have more then one color option, give each a unique id

```
array(
    "name"      => __("Theme Style",'rt_theme_admin'),
    "desc"      => __("Please choose a style for your theme.",'rt_theme_admin'),
    "id"        => THEMESLUG."_17_style",
    "options"   =>  array(
                    "blue"     => "Blue Style",
                    "purple"   => "Purple Style", 
                    "orange"   => "Orange Style",                       
                    "brown"   => "Brown Style",                                                 
                    "rose"   => "Rose Style",       
                    "green"   => "Green Style",     
                    "grey"   => "Grey Style",       
                    "gold"   => "Gold Style",                               
                    ),
    "default"   => "blue", 
    "type"      => "select"),  
array(
    "name"      => __("Theme Style",'rt_theme_admin'),
    "desc"      => __("Please choose a style for your theme.",'rt_theme_admin'),
    "id"        => THEMESLUG."_17_style2",
    "options"   =>  array(
                    "blue"     => "Blue Style",
                    "purple"   => "Purple Style", 
                    "orange"   => "Orange Style",                       
                    "brown"   => "Brown Style",                                                 
                    "rose"   => "Rose Style",       
                    "green"   => "Green Style",     
                    "grey"   => "Grey Style",       
                    "gold"   => "Gold Style",                               
                    ),
    "default"   => "blue", 
    "type"      => "select"),
```

And then in theme.php

```
$themeId = "";
    if($pathname == 'domain2.com')
       $themeId =  THEMESLUG."_17_style2";
    else 
       $themeId = THEMESLUG."_17_style";

    wp_register_style('theme-skin',THEMEURI . '/css/'.get_option($themeId).'-style.css', 3 , false, 'all');
```

Comment: thank you Patrick. It makes sense, but is 'pathame' actually a php function for getting the url path? Isn't it REQUEST_URI?

Comment: No pathname isn't a PHP function it's the variable you set with javascript which Patrick overlooked. Yup usually it's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], but Wordpress should have their own function too.

Comment: yeah, as projeqht pointed out, it is <?php get_site_url(); ?>

Comment: yea simply forgot to put the `$` before the pathname and you dont set it from javascript, you just get it in the php like with the get_site_url function or just use the get_site_url in the if statement.

Comment: could you please update your answer with the right url call using the <?php get_site_url(); ?>...I tried <?php get_site_url($pathname); ?> but breaks my site

Comment: you dont pass anything to get_site_url, $pathname was just the variable you were using in your question so its what i used. You can also get the current site url using get_option('siteurl')

Comment: ok cool, using get_site_url($pathname) works, but when I specify a different color in the dropdown box, it does not capture it...

Comment: OK, so in get_site_url($pathname); $pathname will store the url right?

Comment: no you dont pass anything to get_site_url, just do $pathname = get_site_url();  or $pathname = get_option('siteurl');

Comment: OK, cool , did it, but still no change. I am going to update my question with what I changed in what file, then please tell me if you see anything wrong